# Why can the same task be at different cgroups

Tags: linux, kernel, task

I cat /cgroup/memory/tasks and /cgroup/cpuset/tasks, and I found a lot of duplicate tasks. Isn't it that a task can only appear in one cgroup hierarchy? I am not very familiar with the cgroup mechanism, and does memory and cpuset just control different aspects of behaviour of a task?

More specifically, what happens if different subsystems' behaviour conflicts with another which the task both pertains to?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing together 2 priciples: any process is always member of some cgroup, but this works with respect to the cgroup hierarchy (which are independent of each other). So every process will be a member of some cgroup in each cgroup hierarchy you have defined (usually mounted in `/cgroup/HIERARCHY_NAME`).

Eg. when you configure machine to have 2 hierarchies:

- mounted in `/cgroup/memory` associated with `memory` cgroup controller
- mounted in `/cgroup/cpuset` associated with `cpuset` cgroup controller

you will start with both files `/cgroup/cpuset/tasks` and `/cgroup/memory/tasks` containing pids for all running processess, until you create new cgroup and put some process in it. So no wonder you see the same pids here.

Moreover since cgroup hierarchies are independent, you are not able to connect cgroup controller to more than one hierarchy - which eliminates obvious conflicts.